# how to get the private Node to a Station

Tags: java

This is one of the java classes from my project. I need to get data from inside but i am having trouble. Perhaps someone can help.

```
public class LRTRoute<T> implements RouteInterface<T> {
    private Node firstNode; 
    private int  length;



    private class Node {
      private Station    data; 
      private Node next; 

         private Node(Station data) {
             this.data = data;
             this.next = null;  
         } 

         private Node(Station data, Node next) {
             this.data = data;
             this.next = next;  
         } 

         private Station getData() {
             return data;
         } 

         private void setData(Station data) {
             this.data = data;
         } 

         private Node getNextNode() {
             return next;
         } 

         private void setNextNode(Node next) {
             this.next = next;
         } 
     } 


    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() {
          boolean result;

          if (length == 0)  
              result = true;
          else 
              result = false;

          return result;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean add(int newPosition, Station newEntry) {                                                      
         boolean isSuccessful = true;

         if ((newPosition >= 1) && (newPosition <= length+1)) { 
             Node newNode = new Node(newEntry); 

             if (isEmpty() || (newPosition == 1))   {     
                 newNode.next = firstNode;                          
                 firstNode = newNode;
             }
             else {                                                   
                 Node nodeBefore = getNodeAt(newPosition - 1);
                 Node nodeAfter = nodeBefore.next;
                 newNode.next = nodeAfter;
                 nodeBefore.next = newNode;
             } 

                length++;
         }
         else
             isSuccessful = false;

         return isSuccessful;
      }



    private Node getNodeAt(int givenPosition) {
         Node currentNode = firstNode;


         for (int counter = 1; counter < givenPosition; counter++)
             currentNode = currentNode.next;

         return currentNode;
     }
```

I need help here.
I need to get the data in the Node and send it to another java class... 
The Node is private, so the Node.getData() does not work.

```
    public Station getStationDetail(int givenPosition){
        Station stationDetail = new Station();
        Node newNode = Node.getData();


        return stationDetail ;

    }


    @Override
    public Station getEntry(int givenPosition) {
          Station result = null;  

         if ((givenPosition >= 1) && (givenPosition <= length)) {
             result = getNodeAt(givenPosition).data;
          } 

             return result;
            }

    @Override
    public int getLength() {
        return length;
     } 



}
```

Comment: "so that the Node.getData() cannot works.." the method is not static! What you are trying to do is not clear at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make these public (instead of private) and then will work:

```
         private Node(Station data, Node next) {
         this.data = data;
         this.next = next;  
     } 

     private Station getData() {
         return data;
     } 

     private void setData(Station data) {
         this.data = data;
     } 

     private Node getNextNode() {
         return next;
     } 

     private void setNextNode(Node next) {
         this.next = next;
     }
```

Usually the getters and setters should be public, in the end that's the reason that you create them to have control over the inputs and outputs of the object.

Edited based on comment:

Even though the Node class is used only by the LRTRoute Class the methods should be protected or public to have at access from LRTRoute class.

Second you need a getter in the LRTRoute to get the Node instance, only after this you can do something like:

```
LRTRoute<T> obj = new ...;
obj.getNode().getData(); // <-what you need
```

Or second possibility is to make this static:

```
     private static Station data;
     public static Station getData() {
         return data;
     }
```

And the class Node public.
Hope this helps you!

Comment: the class is use in this LRTRoute class only.. thats why i put private..
btw.. it still cannot work after i change to public

Comment: I edited my last part of the post, hope that this clarifies it and I'm waiting for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you use a nested class generally meaning that the class is used only within Outer class and nowhere else. This is the recommended approach.

Use this documentation for your reference http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

And you would need the object of the outer class LRTRoute before you can 'get' the Node information.

So what you do need, based on your above approach would be

Create set and get methods for

```
private Node firstNode; 
public Node getFirstNode() {
    return firstNode;
}
public void setFirstNode(Node obj) {
    this.firstNode = obj;
}
```

Next use the object of your outer class to get your Node details.

```
LRTRoute object=new LRTRoute();
object.getNFirstNode().getData(); //This would fetch what you are looking for.
```